# PostgreSQL sub-query array return full rows instead of single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    s.*,
    array(
        SELECT m.id
        FROM swarm_machine sm
        JOIN machine m
        ON sm.machine_id = m.id
        WHERE swarm_id = s.id
    ) as machines
FROM swarm s
WHERE group_id = 48
```

Instead of returning just the machine ids `SELECT m.id`, i would like to return all the columns in the row instead `SELECT m.*`. PostgreSQL doesn't seem to allow this, but I was hoping that the community could help be figure it out.

I can always do this with 2 queries, but if PostgreSQL can do it for me I'd rather avoid the round trip.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7481/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres allows it.  Just refer to the record:

```
SELECT s.*,
       ARRAY(SELECT m
             FROM swarm_machine sm JOIN
                  machine m
                 ON sm.machine_id = m.id
             WHERE swarm_id = s.id
            ) as machines
FROM swarm s;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d7481/12) is a SQL Fiddle.